# Android if statement - if a string contains any of the strings from an array

Tags: java, android, arrays, if-statement, comparison

Can you give me a hand please.

I need to do a check, to check if the userCode matches any code in my string array or if the oldUser code also matches any code from the array

```
String[] code = {"1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555"};

String userCode;
String oldUser;

if (userCode.equals(code) || oldUser.equals(code)) {

RUN 

} else { die }
```

thanks

Comment: `Arrays.binarySearch(code, userCode) == 0` if you want speed in searching the array.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin You also must ensure the array is sorted before you can use Arrays.binarySearch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve a simple verification you can loop through your array 
OR
Easy way to do it

```
List< String > code = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555" } );

String userCode;
String oldUser;

if (code.contains(userCode) || code.contains(oldUser)) {

 //doStuff() 

} else { 
    return; 
}
```

Comment: I would suggest changing String[] code to List< String > code = Arrays.asList( new String[] { ... } ); To avoid recreating a new List object twice in the if statement.

Comment: Yes that could be a nice optimization

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
boolean contains = Arrays.asList(arr).contains(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop the array and check each entry with your user values

```
 String[] code = {"1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555"};

 for (int i = 0; i < code.length; i++) {
     if (userCode.equals(code[i]) || oldUser.equals(code[i])) {
          //do
     }
 }
```

Or using `Arrays.asList()`,

```
List<String> codes = Arrays.asList("1111", "2222", "3333", "4444", "5555");

if (codes.contains(userCode) || codes.contains(oldUser)) {
          //do
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a foreach with a boolean var

```
boolean isTheSame;
For(String myArrayCodes; code;) {
  if (userCode.equals(myArrayCodes) || oldUser.equals(myArrayCodes))
    isTheSame = true;
  break;
  }
}

if (isTheSame) { // usercode or oldUser is on array
 doSomething();
}
else {
}
```